# Is it possible in Firefox to always hide the title for one website?

Tags: firefox

I always visit one website which I don't want others to see the title of.

I want that whenever I open that site my title of that site changes to something else or hide.

There is a addonon in Firefox which can hide the title of window, but I have to manually click on hide title.

Is there something which can do it automatically for a particular website?

Comment: sounds to me like something is showing up in your history that you don't want mom and pop to find ;)

Comment: If you just change the title shown in your history, you mom and pop can still search the names of URLs of pages and pictures, browse through the cache, etc…

Comment: no no its not history , suppose i have 5 tabs open and one tabs title shows some Adult title , when someone is looking at all tabs title i want to change that title not in history but when i am viewing live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Greasemonkey.

Write a script that changes the page title.

Comment: Or use Private Browsing mode; but you have to activate it manually, every time, and it doesn't keep track of your history, so visited links are not shown as such.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel in private browsing, the window title is still the tab title and thus visible in the taskbar

Comment: @Xerus Fair enough, but look at the first comment about the OP's possible intention.

Answer (score 3):

As Graphain said, use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/).

And, because it's easy fun, I have written the GM script for you. :)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Title Changer for web page XXX
// @namespace      Google
// @include        YourWebsiteHere.tld/*
// ==/UserScript==


window.addEventListener ("load", Greasemonkey_main, false);
Greasemonkey_main ();


function Greasemonkey_main ()
{
    document.title  = 'This is NOT the Highly Incriminating website you are looking for!';
}
```

.

A place to find additional scripts is: http://userscripts.org/ .

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle Firefox's **full screen mode** - that will hide the title and URL.